# ¿Porque spring boot no em retorna el token alutilizar le refres token, si no un 401?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, refreshtoken

mestoy tratando de optener un nuevo token utlizando la seguridad de springboot pero este solo me retorna un 401 a postman.

esta es la peticion que gago:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la configuracion de seguridad he añadido esa ruta pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar.

```
package com.bolsadeideas.apirest.auth;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    // configuracion centralizada de la seguridad de las rutas
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/clientes", "/api/clientes/page/**", "/api/uploads/img/**", "/images/**","/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/oauth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/clientes/{id}").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/clientes/upload").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/clientes").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/clientes/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
    }

    // PASO 1 crear en bean (metodo inyectable) de la configuracion del cors
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type", "Authorization"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }

    // PASO 2 registra esta configuracion y la pasa a los interceptores del spring security
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter(){
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource()));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }


}
```

la ruta que devuelve el token normal y el refresh funciona correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por si ayuda ver la configuracion completa de la seguridad se puede ver aca el proyecto completo : https://github.com/Gerguevara/rest-api-springboot/tree/main/src/main/java/com/bolsadeideas/apirest/auth

Comment: No veo la configuracion del oauth, por favor de poner el código completo.